# Поиск индекса объекта в массиве через значение свойства объекта

Tags: javascript

```
this.accounts = [   
{
      name: "admin",
      surname: "admin",
      username: "admin",
      regpass: "12345"
    },   
    {
      name: "1",
      surname: "1",
      username: "1",
      regpass: "1111"
    }   
]   
let accountindex = this.accounts.indexOf(JSON.parse(this.loginForm.value.name))
```

`this.loginForm.value.name` это значение input из html

Answer (score 3):

```js
this.accounts = [   
  {
    name: "admin",
    surname: "admin",
    username: "admin",
    regpass: "12345"
  },   
  {
    name: "1",
    surname: "1",
    username: "1",
    regpass: "1111"
  }   
];
let index = this.accounts.findIndex( el => el.name === "admin" );
//let index = this.accounts.findIndex( el => el.name === this.loginForm.value.name );
console.log(index);
```